# trigger only once in document click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script

```
$(document).on("click", "#ocs", function(){
    alert("ASdasd");
});
```

but on a unknown reasons, it trigger the click twice. I can surely use

```
$("#ocs").unbind().click(function(){
    alert("ASdasd");
});
```

to make it not trigger twice but for my requirements I don't use

```
$("#ocs").unbind().click(function(){
```

so any ideas how to do unbind() or not to make trigger twice using

```
$(document).on("click", "selector", function(){
```

?

Comment: Can you show some HTML? It should not be triggering twice in the first place

Comment: Its a system, very heavy html.

Comment: Well, its either the handler is attached twice, or you have two elements with the same id

Comment: Did you set that inside a JS function? E.g. `function store() { $(document).on("click", "#ocs", function(){ ... }) }`

Comment: @AmmarCSE: ill take not of that, ill check that attached twice and same id stuffs, thank you

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan: i use document ready.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `one` for that

```
$(document).one("click", "#ocs", function(){
    alert("ASdasd");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
$('#abc').bind('click', function() {
   $(this).unbind('click');
   alert('Clicked and Unbind');
```

});

The bind does allow you to re-bind the click event later if needed.